# how to remove additional authors from VLDB template?

Tags: sectioning

I am working on a report using the [VLDB template](http://vldb2018.lncc.br/download/vldb_style_sample.zip). I am getting an extra section called `Additional Authors' even though I have given all the authors names on the front page along with the right author name numbers.
This is the following code. I am not sure what is activating the additional authors section.

```
\numberofauthors{4} 

\author{
\alignauthor
Lini Thomas\\
       \affaddr{IIIT-Hyderabad}\\
       \affaddr{Hyderabad, India.}\\
       \email{lini.thomas@iiit.ac.in}
% 2nd. author
\alignauthor
Amar Budhiraja\\
       \affaddr{Microsoft R\&D}\\
       \affaddr{Hyderabad, India.}\\
       \email{ambudhir@microsoft.com}
% 3rd. author
\and
\alignauthor Satyanarayana R Valluri\\
       \affaddr{Oracle}\\
       \affaddr{California, USA}\\
       \email{satya.valluri@oracle.com}
% 4th. author
\alignauthor Kamalakar Karlapalem\\
       \affaddr{IIIT-Hyderabad}\\
       \affaddr{Hyderabad, India.}\\
       \email{kamal@iiit.ac.in}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the problem is with vldb.cls file. In vldb.cls file, change :

```
\def\addauthorsection{\ifnum\originalaucount>3
    \section{Additional Authors}\the\addauthors
  \fi}
```

to :

```
\def\addauthorsection{\ifnum\originalaucount>6
    \section{Additional Authors}\the\addauthors
  \fi}
```